# Check if PDO support else use mysqli() php

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have my site using mysqli. Now I learnt PDO, and want to implement it.

The question is:

How do I check if the server has Pdo Support using php to connect?

```
if(PDO support){

 //connect with pdo
 //use pdo functions
  }
  else{


  //connect with mysqli
  // use mysqli functions
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense

Comment: You can do `if (class_exists('PDO'))` but you shouldn't. Don't write your whole app to work with both varieties at the same time, that's going to be a real pain to maintain.

Comment: Just install the one you need and use it. Why check??

Comment: Use phpinfo() on your server.

Comment: Better use some lightweight ORM like [readbean](https://redbeanphp.com) that way you don't have to worry PDO/mysqli

Comment: the site is currently running with mysqli...I want to implement pdo. Cant I check if the server has pdo enabled, using php?

Answer (score 1):

There is a check to see if a php extension is loaded, here is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) from PHP.net

Their example applied to your situation would be:

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded('pdo')) {
    //use mysqli
} else {
    //use pdo
}
```

Comment: It is recommend to also check to ensure the specific database support for PDO is loaded `pdo_mysql`, `pdo_sqlite`, etc.

Comment: PDO is enabled by default, so you'd need to have quite a strange hoster that explicitly disables PDO. But as @fyrye correctly said, you could check that the appropriate driver is loaded (but again, a hoster normally configures PHP so that the offered databases can be used).